# How to disable Print Chart button when there is no Chart present

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

I have the following code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CollectionsBySuburb", "DashBoard")',
        data: { Period: 2015 },
        success: function (data) {
            var catArr = data.map(function (o) { return o.Category; });
            var paidArr = data.map(function (o) { return parseInt(o.TotalTax + o.TotalArrears + o.TotalDiscount); });
            var outArr = data.map(function (o) { return parseInt(o.TotalBillAmount - (o.TotalTax + o.TotalArrears + o.TotalDiscount)); });

            $('#CollectionsBySuburb').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            alert();
                        }
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                colors: ["#62BD00", "#FA1B02"],
                title: {
                    text: 'Amount  Collection By Suburb'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: catArr
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount  ( '' )'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    reversed: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{series.name}</span>: GH₵ <b>{point.y}</b>'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Paid',
                    data: paidArr
                }, {
                    name: 'Outstanding',
                    data: outArr
                }]
            });
        }
    });
 $.ajax({
 //Rendering other chart here
 });
 $.ajax({
 //Rendering other chart here
 });
 $.ajax({
 //Rendering other chart here
 });
 $.ajax({
 //Rendering other chart here
 });
```

So now my requirement is since I have multiple charts when I click on Print Button I want to check if a chart is present if present then enabling the options to so that user can download it else hiding the options to download. I tried using different ways but cannot do it. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) and then iterate on all series to check if all are hidden. If yes, then you can hide a button by `this.chart.exportSVGElements[0].hide();` function.

```
events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    var series = this.chart.series,
                        index = this.index,
                        allHidden = this.visible ? false : true;

                    $.each(series, function(i, serie){
                        if(serie.visible && i !== index)
                            allHidden = true;
                    });

                    if(!allHidden) {
                        this.chart.exportSVGElements[0].hide();
                    } else {
                        this.chart.exportSVGElements[0].show();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jL0u6o82/

Comment: here is what all I required is. I was looking for the legendItemClick event(as per larrydahooster thanks for his help too)  to handle. I got it another way counting the no. of charts and then getting the button and disabling it and even that worked. But this seems to be much more professional. Thanks.

Comment: Can you plz also tell me how to hide the same button when I want to print the chart in. As in the preview I get the button as well which I want to hide when the user wants to download the chart.

Comment: For exported chart to images, you can setup this options in [chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions), but for print, you need to catch menuItems, and hide element before call print() function. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jL0u6o82/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use

    `exporting: {
        enabled: false
    }`

at highchart construct function.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting

Answer (score 1):

I do not completely understand your requirements, so i will demonstrate different techniques.

1. Disable the export button if no data available:

   ```
   exporting: {
       enabled: data.length > 0 ? true : false
   }
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/v08j30n3/1/

2. Remove specific buttons (pseudo condtion here):

   ```
   function filterButtons(data) {

       //get default buttons
       var options = Highcharts.getOptions();
       var defaultButtons =   options.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
       var wantedButtons = [];
       // add your condition here. I simply remove the printChart button.   
       for (var button in defaultButtons) {
           if(defaultButtons[button].textKey !== 'printChart') {
               wantedButtons.push(defaultButtons[button]);
           } else {
               if (data.length > 0) {
                  wantedButtons.push(defaultButtons[button]);
               }
           }

       }
   return wantedButtons;
   }
   ```

And then within your highchart object

```
exporting: {        
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems:   filterButtons(data)
             }
       }
```

See code here: http://jsfiddle.net/v08j30n3/4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this is close to my requirements. As in the fiddle if I click the Series1 then I can see the chart is disappearing. So, now if I click the button to print I want to hide download options.

Comment: What do you mean by "click the Series1"? The button? I am sorry, i don't really get the point.

Comment: I mean the download options which are displayed should  be hidden when I click on the Series marked as bold. Since when I click on <b>Series</b> the chart disappers. I hope this help's.

Comment: Ah okay, i think i got want you want. You want to trigger the change of the button when you click on a series in the legend? Since i am short on time at the moment, i can't provide a solution yet. But then you have to hook yourself into  'legendItemClick' see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/LDMAQ/